# Xquery SQL contains

Tags: sql, xquery

I'm trying to query the following XML for all `ContentNode` nodes that contain a comma.

```
<Node xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx">
  <SubNode>
    <SubSubNode>
      <ContentNode>Data, </ContentNode>
```

The following returns 0 results:

`select * 
from Table 
where [XML].exist('/Node/SubNode/SubSubNode [contains(ContentNode[1],",")]')=1`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **What database system**, and which version?? *SQL* is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... features like XML support are very vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** you're using....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default namespace and you need to use that in your query.
Have a look at [WITH XMLNAMESPACES (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177607.aspx)

```
with xmlnamespaces(default 'http://schemas.xxx.xxx.xxx')
select *
from Table
where [XML].exist('/Node/SubNode/SubSubNode [contains(ContentNode[1],",")]')=1
```